# How could i pass some variable into twig from a form?

Tags: theming, forms, 8

I have a template for a block and i need some configuration in it.  is there a way for me to take some value from a field in the form and put it in a variable for a twig template?

```
{#<!-- Step 1: Create the containing elements. -->#}
<section id="auth-button"></section>
<section id="view-selector-1"></section>
<section id="timeline"></section>
<section id="timeline2"></section>
<section id="authorPie"></section>
<section id="timegraph"></section>

{#<!-- Step 2: Load the library. -->#}

<script>
(function(w,d,s,g,js,fjs){
  g=w.gapi||(w.gapi={});g.analytics={q:[],ready:function(cb){this.q.push(cb)}};
  js=d.createElement(s);fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  js.src='https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js';
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);js.onload=function(){g.load('analytics')};
}(window,document,'script'));
</script>

<script>
gapi.analytics.ready(function() {

  // Step 3: Authorize the user.
  var CLIENT_ID = 'THIS IS WHAT I NEED TO CONFIGURE';
```

Comment: The answer is almost certainly yes, but without seeing your code there's no point trying to guess what the solution might look like...

Comment: i added my twig.  or did you want my configuration page

Comment: Don't need to the see form as such, but where are you saving the data from it? The basic idea is to implement a preprocess function for the template, add a render array with the drupalSettings library attached, and add a setting for your module with the value you need in JS (then render the array). Then in your template you can use `drupalSettings.foo.bar`

Comment: Im not sure what you mean by "it".  I have a module  with the element in a form.  in that form I want to put in some text save it and then use that text from the form as a variable in the twig template